# “Your face looks like my sister's friend face” or “my sister's friend”?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe, double-possessives

Which sentence should I use to show that she has the same face and should I use *feature* instead of *face*?

> "Your face looks like my sister's friend face"

or just

> "Your face looks like my sister's friend"

Answer (score 2):

I would use neither.

It is normal to say that someone *looks like* someone else, ergo

> You look like my **sister's** friend.

If I wanted to point out that their eyes were similar, I'd say

> The colour of your eyes look like my **sister's friend's**

The *friend* "belongs" to the sister, and the eyes belong to her or him, hence we need two possessive apostrophes.

Answer (score 1):

I would write:

> Your face looks like the face of my sister's friend.

or:

> Your face looks like the face of a friend of my sister's.

Your two proposed options don't work for me, because the first one would need the addition of possessive **'s** after "friend", and the second one compares a part with a whole (your face = sister's friend).

Yes, you can use the word **features**, but you'd need to remodel the sentence to something like

> Your facial features remind me of my sister's friend.

Comment: Is it correct to put: "Your face looks like the face of my sister's friend's."?

Comment: @dan - apparently yes, but I personally don't like using two **'s**. But it must be correct, according to Mari-Lou's answer

Comment: We actually use those all the time: my brother's friend's bike. My father's brother's car. Even though they may seem awkward.